# Create Server on VirtualBox visible from outside, host is not behind router

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to create a web server on a Virtual Machine. I would be happy even if I could access it with something like http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:[port_no] Everything is installed but the step of facing the outside world presents some problems for me, mainly because I am not behind a router. Here are some details:

**Host OS**: Ubuntu 12.04
The Host is connected to the world through a static IP (Ethernet), there is no router (it is a PC on a University campus and there is no DHCP). There is no firewall from the University administrators.

**Guest VM**: Ubuntu 14.04 (no windows environment) on VirtualBox.
When using NAT I can connect to the Internet, but if I understand correctly, a Bridged adapter would mean I need either a new static IP or a to be behind a router. When I enable the Bridged Adapter I get an IP 10.0.2.15, I am guessing on an adhocLAN, and ofcourse it does not work.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, this is definitely possible. You just need to do some port-forwarding settings from your Virtualbox interface.

Go to Settings -> Network -> Port Forwarding. Then, add a new rule. In the host port, add some port which you wish to use, say `1212`. In the guest port, add port `80` which is the default for apache.

Start your virtual machine and that's it. Your web-server can now be reached from your host machine as: http://localhost:1212, and from the external world as `<Public-IP>:1212`.

Screenshot: 
[image]

PS: You don't need to use bridged connection or anything like that. Just keep it at NAT.

Comment: wow, it worked, so simple and yet so elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help :)